# Does a thermostatic water valve works when reverse connected?

Tags: valve, hot-water

I installed a regular shower thermostatic water valve to feed a washing machine (the internal heating failed and we want to extend its working life - I also think I should have done this earlier, as central gas warm water is cheaper than the electric heating of the washing machine).

When testing the project, I figured out that the thermostatic valve is working on reverse. I need to turn the valve towards its indicated (+) to get colder water and vice-versa.

I double checked all connections and I'm positive that warm and cold inlets are connected as they should, or -at least- as color coded in the red/blue connections of the valve.

I'm assuming that either the color-coding or the +/- signs are wrongly indicated on the valve. I suppose I can return it to the shop on the grounds that it doesn't work as expected, but it would be a hassle to dismount/return/reinstall.

What I'm wondering: if what's wrong is the color coding of the connections and the valve is actually connected in reverse with relation to how the temperature control has been designed internally, will it keep on working?  or will this "cross-wiring" eventually damage the internal mechanism?  (In which case I would be better off returning the valve to the shop)

[image]

Comment: What is the valve designed to do if the incoming water is too hot for its setpoint?

Comment: @harper mix with cold water.

Comment: ...and when it wants cold water, which inlet will it will try to get that from?